# Fetch input parameter using a Calculated View in HANA

Tags: hana

I have a SAP HANA studio Calculated view configuration query.

I have created a Calculated view (IP) to calculate my input parameters and I wanted use these input parameters for Main Calculated view "AB".

Can someone explain how it can be done in Edit Input Parameter window so that my view AB directly fetches value from IP?

Also IP has only one row.

Do I need to push the data from Input Parameter CV to a table and then use Input Parameter Type ="Derived from table"?

regards,
Umar Abdullah

Comment: It's duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079927/set-input-parameters-from-the-data-in-on-cv-as-input-parameters-in-other-cv-in-h/53080628#53080628

Comment: Question is posted after my question with change in Title of question.