# Set input parameters from the data in on CV as input parameters in other CV in HANA

Tags: hana

I have a SAP HANA studio Calculated view configuration query

I have created a Calculated view (IP) to calculate my input parameters. The input parameters is a row in IP and I want use data in IP as my input parameter for Main Calculated view "AB" Can someone explain how it can be done in Edit Input Parameter window so that My view AB directly fetches value from IP?

Also IP has only one row.

Do I need to push the data from Input Parameter CV to a table and then use Input Parameter Type ="Derived from table"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to use output of one view as a source for value help for main view.
In that case you should do the following:
[image: Input parameter]

1. In your main view open input parameter editor as set *Parameter Type* as Column
2. As a *View/Table for value help* section select your second view which contains desired output
3. As a *Reference Column* set the column which contains the data which you want to display